# If $z_{n} = a_{n} + ib_{n}$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_{n}=p \neq 0$, then $\sin(z_{n}) \nrightarrow 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z_{n} = a_{n} + ib_{n}$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_{n}=p \neq 0$, then $\sin(z_{n}) \nrightarrow 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

I know
$$
\sin(z_{n}) = \sin(a_{n})\cosh(b_{n}) + i \sinh(b_{n})\cos(a_{n})
$$
then
$$
|\sin(z_{n})|^{2}= \sin^{2}(a_{n})\cosh^{2}(b_{n}) +  \sinh^{2}(b_{n})\cos^{2}(a_{n}).
$$
Furthermore, we have
$$
\cosh^{2}(b_{n}) \to \cosh^{2}(p) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \sinh^{2}(b_{n}) \to \sinh^{2}(p)
$$
And I know that $\sin(a_{n})$ and $\cos(a_{n})$ don't cancel out simultaneously.

But with all this information, I'm not able to show what I want.

Comment: I presume $n$ is an integer here, am I correct, @AndressaMask?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Yes, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$
> |\sin(z_{n})|^{2}= \sin^{2}(a_{n})\cosh^{2}(b_{n}) +  \sinh^{2}(b_{n})\cos^{2}(a_{n}).
> $$

Note that:  $\cosh^{2}(b_{n})=1+\sinh^{2}(b_{n})$, then we have

$$
|\sin(z_{n})|^{2}= \sin^{2}(a_{n})+  \sinh^{2}(b_{n})\ge\sinh^{2}(b_{n})
$$
Since $\lim \sinh(b_n)=\sinh(p)$,

$$\exists N\in \mathbb{N}^+, \forall n>N, ~|\sinh(b_n)|\ge\frac{1}2|\sinh(p)| $$
$$
\Rightarrow |\sin(z_{n})|^{2}\ge\sinh^{2}(b_{n})\ge\frac{1}4\sinh^{2}(p)>0,~~~\forall n>N
$$

Comment: Why $\sinh^{2}(p) > 0$?

Comment: $\sinh(p)=0$ iff $p=0$ @AndressaMask

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Very fine solution!

Comment: thank you, glad you like it.@user

Answer (score 4):

From your work we have that

$$\sin(z_{n}) = \sin(a_{n})\cosh(b_{n}) + i \sinh(b_{n})\cos(a_{n}) \to 0 \iff \sin(a_{n})\to 0 \;\land \; \cos(a_{n})\to 0$$

which is not possible for the reason you have already noticed and which can be proved, for example, by contradiction.

Comment: But and if $\cosh(p) =0 $ and $\cos(a_{n}) =0$ ?

Comment: This is *the* way to go (though not necessarily the *only way*), +1!  =)

Comment: @AndressaMask Isn't it $\cosh(p) =0 \iff p=0$?

Comment: @user $\cosh(p) = 0$, if $ p = i\pi n - i\pi/2$. But $p > 0$, that is, $\cosh(p) \neq 0$. And that?

Comment: @AndressaMask The imaginary part of $z_n$ is a real number, isn't it? That is I'm assuming of course that $b_{n} \to p\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: $\cosh(p)\ge 1, \forall p\in\mathbb{R}$ @user

Comment: @MathFail Yes of course! nice to be mentioned.